# JSON API filtering standards for more complex queries

Tags: json, api, get, filtering, json-api

I am writing a REST api using ruby on rails. I am using [json api](http://jsonapi.org/) as a guide for the standards to use when building the api.

I am trying to figure out the best way to use filtering in the GET requests. The json api [recommendations for filtering](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering) only include where something is exactly equal to. eg.

```
GET /comments?filter[post]=1
```

How would I go about filtering for greater than, less than, not equal to, like, contains etc.?

I have done a lot of searching through google results but there doesn't seem to be a standard of the best way to do the filtering. There are some suggestions for example [this one](http://discuss.jsonapi.org/t/share-propose-a-filtering-strategy/257).

I'm looking for a solid spec or standard that I can refer to specifically for the filtering for my api, as the json api spec is very limited when it comes to filtering.

Comment: OData filter URL standard is a good option: https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/

Comment: This link provides some details: https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/filtering

Answer (score 1):

I looks like there are a few more resources for this now 6 years later.

From what I read quickly it looks like the JSON:API spec may not specify this exactly. However this supposedly compliant framework documentation looks helpful:

https://www.jsonapi.net/usage/reading/filtering.html

Going by their method you could do this

```
GET /games?filter=greaterThan(id,20345)
GET /games?filter=lessThan(id,345334)
```

See the link as they have a lot of other standard looking filters that could be useful.